# PHP reading child script output with fgets()

Tags: php

I'm running ScriptA and ScriptB, A executes B. B `echos` messages after it finishes each of its functions. Thing is: B's functions may get stuck because they request data to a slow server with short session expiring so I'm trying to kill B after certain time has passed since the last echoed message. Here is an example:
**ScriptB:**

```
echo "string1\n";  
sleep(1);  
echo "string2\n";  
sleep(1);  
echo "string3\n";  
sleep(1);  
echo "string4\n";  
sleep(3);  
echo "string5\n";
```

**ScriptA**

```
$cmd = "php ScriptB";
$timeout_tolerance = 2; // 
$last_response = time(); // start time

ob_implicit_flush(true);
ob_end_flush();

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);
flush();
$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, array());
echo "here is 1\n";
if (is_resource($process)) {
    while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        print $s;
        $m = $s;
        $last_response = time();
        while ($s === $m) {
            echo "here is 2\n";
            $m = fgets($pipes[1]);
            if((time() - $last_response) > $timeout_tolerance){
                echo "here is 3\n";
                break;
            }
            echo "here is 4\n";
            sleep(2);
        }
    }
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);
    echo "here is 5\n";
}
```

When I run Script A this is what I get as an output:

```
here is 1
string1
here is 2
here is 4
string3
here is 2
here is 4
string5
here is 2
here is 4
here is 5
```

As you may see; `string2` nor `string4` are outputted and scriptB should be killed before `string5` is echoed. I know this is an error on my code, thing is I have never used functions such as `fgets()` and I'm having a hard time understanding them.

Comment: You may want to rethink your strategy; It may be better to use a RESTful response than a time based response.

Comment: @Sablefoste thanks for the answer, I am not following you though. Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @Sablefoste how is the response type connected to the problem?

Comment: Script B should provide a predictable response to Script A.  If Server B is slow, you still want an answer out of it, right?  So Server A should periodically ask Server B if it is done with the calculation; if it is not done, reply with `'not done'`.  If it is done, reply with the answer.  I would have Server B write to a database (if you aren't comfortable with `fgets()`) the final answer so it is ready to go when queried.

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071896/php-kill-proc-open-process-on-different-file.

Comment: @GreensterRox mm not really